# How to use SSH connection from inside thread using omnithread library?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, omnithreadlibrary

I use Devart TScSSHClient component to start a SSH connection to a device, after connecting I use SSHterminal to send a command and retrieve the result.
My question How can I end the thread manually (omnithread that I started) after receiving the result from the sshShell component? I can't tell how long it will take to get the result because it depends on the device processing time.

Thank you for your advice

Comment: Can I use while (true) and (not doStop)..... and doStop:=false (wherever needed)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.